# Medalha socrático não "evolui"

Tags: suporte, bug, medalhas

> Cross-post: [Does the Socratic badge require that questions with votes have a specific lifetime?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305183/198279)

Atualmente a medalha socrático acusa como tendo 92/100, a descrição da medalha diz:

> Fazer 100 boas perguntas em dias diferentes e manter um histórico de pergunta positiva.

Conforme a minha consulta eu tenho [**user:3635 score:1 is:question closed:no**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3635%20score%3a1%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) eu tenho 105 perguntas que se adéquam, claro que tenho que remover as extras, pois só pode contar uma por dia, então essas foram as vezes que fiz mais de uma pergunta com upvote por dia:

- 20/11/16
- 8/11/16
- 1/08/16
- 19/07/16
- 28/02/16
- 27/05/15
- 27/04/15
- 17/02/15 x4

Foram *11 perguntas* que não devem entrar na conta, ou seja *105-11 = 94*, então conforme as minhas contas a medalha deveria aparecer 94/100 e **não** 92/100.

Ou seja seriam as duas perguntas que fiz nos últimos dias deveriam ter somado 94.

Será que é algum bug, pois faz muito tempo que tenho notado que estou no 92 e não saiu disto:

[image: medalha socrático no perfil exibindo 92/100]

Isto é um BUG ou falta algum requisito?

---

### [edição]

Eu criei as seguintes queries no data.stackexchange:

- [Count Socratic progress](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/775641/count-socratic-progress)
- [Show post to Socratic badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/775643/show-post-to-socratic-badge)

Note que ambos são basicamente a mesma query, mas um retorna os links e o outro o total, ambas dão 92 (no que trás os links basta usar text-only e verá a soma no final da resposta).

Então conforme as queries esta correto, eu tenho 92 duas, mas observem um detalhe:

> [image: resultado da querie]

Mas as perguntas que deveriam aparecer, devido ao `ORDER by Id DESC` deveriam ser:

- [Existe alguma maneira pythônico de fazer "slice" de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265066/3635)
- [Como comunicar abas com uma extensão/add-on e armazenar as variáveis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265489/3635)

Mas não são exibidas, creio que isto seja algo com o cache

### [edição 2]

Acabou de ir para 93, no entanto não fiz nenhum pergunta nova:

> [image: 93/100 para medalha socratico]

Ou seja, com certeza não é problema nas contas.

Comment: Em algum momento essas perguntas ficaram negativas?

Comment: @Maniero então mesmo que os ups totais sejam de +1, se eu tiver qualquer -2, tipo: +3-1=2 ela seria desconsiderada?

Comment: Não sei, bem, mas eu acho que se em algum momento ficou negativa pode desarmar para aquele caso. Se tomar o negativo depois não teria problema. Estou especulando. Os critérios das medalhas são complicados e pouco descritivos.

Comment: @Maniero seguindo por esta lógica os upvotes tem que ocorrer em dias diferentes também, ou melhor ocorrer no mesmo dia da pergunta. Então tendo ou não "downvote antes", qualquer coisa tem que ocorrer em dias diferentes. É tá dificil de saber :/ ... ainda sim, fiz duas perguntas recentemente em dias diferentes, ambas consegui upvotes e nenhum downvote, no mesmo dia que foram criadas, ainda sim continuei no 92/100 quando deveria ter ido para 94/100 - *Algo de errado não esta certo*

Comment: É o q sobraria.

Comment: De opção do que ocorre.

Comment: Ah entendi, fala do cache

Answer (score 2):

A fórmula da medalha é a seguinte:

- Conta no máximo uma pergunta por dia distinto;
- Desconsidera perguntas fechadas e com score total negativo;
- (total de perguntas - fechadas - negativadas) / total de perguntas > 0.5

Fonte: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291013/2263584

Note que não interessa se a pergunta tem votos negativos, mas sim se o score total é positivo ou negativo.

Na fonte tem uma query que você pode rodar no sistema da Stack Exchange para ver como você está em relação a essa medalha. A query só não consegue filtrar o caso de mais de uma pergunta por dia.

http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/202517/asking-record

Ela me trouxe 105 perguntas totais para você, com duas excluídas. Subtraindo as duas excluídas e as 11 que você mesmo mencionou como sendo de mesmo dia que outras, dá 92 mesmo.

Comment: Mas esta 92 a meses, e eu fiz +2 perguntas em dias distintos, que não foram deletadas, que tem score positivo. Eu acompanho essa tag a meses.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. talvez algo tenha acontecido a outras duas perguntas suas, para contrabalançar o score.

Comment: Renan eu fiz outras perguntas nesse meio tempo, sei que raramente pergunto algo, até me esforço, mas tenho certeza que nesses ultimos meses fiz mais perguntas, não é possivel que nenhuma tenha feito eu sair do 92, *algo de errado não esta certo*.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP o seu perfil público lista 107 perguntas. Quatro foram fechadas (aparentemente duas foram fechadas de ontem pra hoje). Sobram 103 para contabilizar a medalha. Menos 11 em dias repetidos... A matemática bate, então, talvez tenha acontecido outra coisa. Continue perguntando. As suas perguntas são boas (você tem um dos índices de positivação mais altos no site). Logo logo você ganha a medalha.

Comment: as unicas duas perguntas fechadas são [**`user:3635 is:question closed:yes`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3635+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes), uma foi fechada em 2015 e a outra em 07/2017. Não teve nenhuma fechada recentemente, vou contar novamente pra confirmar e te aviso

Comment: Renan editei a pergunta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6732/3635

Comment: Renan acabou de acontecer https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZfFQ.png. fui pra 93/100 ... com certeza o problema é outra coisa e não as minhas contas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. eu acho que existe algum job que faz essa conta e ele está com problemas :\ eu levaria o caso pro meta geral ou pra suporte técnico mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. ah, eu votei nas perguntas que você linkou. Não sei se isso pode ter afetado.

Comment: Renan esta bom assim https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305183/198279 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. está. Agora, a query continua mostrando que você tem quatro perguntas fechadas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX6rY.png você deletou alguma pergunta? Perguntas deletadas sempre continuarão a assombrar as contas de seus criadores.

Comment: Não você fez confusão, o icone verde é pra alternar, as 4 fechadas são do META, eu montei duas queries, veja a diferença [**meta**](http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/775692/invalids-to-socratic-badge) e [**site principal**](http://data.stackexchange.com/ptme/query/775692/invalids-to-socratic-badge)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. é mesmo. Vamos ver o que o pessoal diz no meta geral então.

Comment: Renan nesses testes achei outro bug https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305185/198279, mas desta vez o bug é só no data.se